# How Can I debug Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010 with out local IIS installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, iis, asp-classic

I am aware that Classic ASP debugging is not possible with Visual Studio 2010 Development server.

I know it is possible with IIS installed locally, but my case was bit tricky. Due to security restrictions, I need to work with Visual Studio 2010 - but without IIS installed locally.

Is there any alternative, workaround, or easy trick to make it possible to debug classic ASP?

Comment: [let me google that for you](https://www.google.at/search?q=debug+asp.net+without+iis&oq=debug+asp.net+without+iis&aqs=chrome..69i57.5891j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=debug+asp.net+without+local+iis&safe=off)

Comment: @sine OP specifically asked for ASP classic, not .NET.

Comment: @sine I needed debugging on Classic ASP trick.

Comment: Would IISExpress be permitted?

Comment: Take a look at Active Local Pages http://www.activelocalpages.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you can run it, the "[Team Remote ASP Debugger](http://www.remotedebugger.com/)" mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874770/25163) to a related question may be of help. It claims to be able to run without special permissions, etc. - but having not tried it myself, I couldn't say if it works for sure.